# Plotlyjs chart rendering without data while data is accessible in console log

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

My chart is not rendering data i fetched from axios. I console logged it and data is accessible but not inside the Plot. I have declared the div in my html file. Empty plot being shown, also data is a global variable so shall be accessible inside the function.

```
<script>
    var data = {};

    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/corp_index/price_chart/5')
         .then(function (response) {
             console.log(response.data);
             data=response.data;
             console.log(data.labels);
         })
    
    var chartData = [{
        x: data.labels,
        y: data.series,
        type:'line',
        }
    ];
    var myDiv = document.getElementById('tester')
    Plotly.newPlot(myDiv, chartData);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code which creates the chart is executed before you have the data, because getting the data is an asynchronous operation. You should put all of that code into the callback.

```
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/corp_index/price_chart/5')
         .then(function (response) {
             console.log(response.data);
             data=response.data;
             console.log(data.labels);
             var chartData = [{
                x: data.labels,
                y: data.series,
                type:'line',
               }
             ];
             var myDiv = document.getElementById('tester')
             Plotly.newPlot(myDiv, chartData);
         })
```